# What language and tools were originally used to develop Sega MD/Genesis games?

Tags: programming-languages, assembly

Someone has suggested to me it was assembler, though I think there were some visual design tools, too. So how did they make it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it was actually assembler. 68 K assembly, as this article [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Genesis_Programming) shows. You can even find the 68K memory map there.

If you are actually interested in doing it, [this](http://www.atariage.com/forums/topic/98540-sega-genesis-programming/) nice post, does contain a whole lot of information.

If you try, you can even find a [sega genesis C](http://www.zophar.net/documents/genesis/sega-genesis-c-compiler.html) compiler ( I haven't tested it myself ),

Answer (score 3):

Many games in the mid90s were developed in C such as Ecco and Sonic Pinball. But most if not all arcade conversions were in Assembly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi The question was "which language" and this is the answer. Can't prove that but look reasonable.